# Use Chef with a non-Git VCS/DVCS

Tags: git, svn, mercurial, chef-infra

I've just started my research prior to starting to use Chef.

All tutorials and sources state that Git is used as the repository for Chef.

Is Git required? Can I use Mercurial, SVN, etc?

Are there any limitations?

The following picture from getchef.com mentions SVN:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging quite a bit I found the following:

> git and/or github is not required to use Chef. If another version source control system is preferred over git (such as Subversion, Mercurial, or Bazaar) that is just fine.

and

> Download the chef-repo as a tar.gz file and place it into local version source control

and

> (Optional) After the chef-repo is cloned, the history of that repository can be wiped out by removing the ”.git” directory, which allows the initialization of a new repository or to move the chef-repo into another version source control system, such as Subversion, Mercurial, or Bazaar.

..from [here.](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_repository_create.html)

There are no details however, of any limitations this presents, so I would assume there are none.

Comment: None. The information loaded into a chef server is contained in a "chef repository", which is really a file layout convention. See http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_repository.html I also recommend investigating the a tool called spiceweasel that is very useful for loading data from a chef repo into chef server https://github.com/mattray/spiceweasel